How to reconnect a paired device to Android Studio via Wifi?
Yesterday I paired my phone to Android Studio for debugging via Wifi. Everything worked beautifully (well, except that QR code scanning didn't work, I had to use the pairing code method). Today I would like to continue to work with my phone connected via Wifi.
Both in Android Studio as well as on my phone the other device shows up. In Android Studio in Device Manager in the physical tab, and on the my phone in developer options under Wireless debugging. But my phone doesn't show up as an option for running the app in Android Studio.
Do I have to run the pairing process every time I want to work via Wifi with Android Studio and my phone? Or is there a way to simply reconnect the already paired device?
